# What will be Mysql query for group by and order by dictionary style?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to fetch data and print as like dictionary.
**Table:**
blog_tags

```
id name
1  atag1
2  atag2
3  dtag1
4  etag1
5  etag2
6  ctag1
7  ctag2
8  ctag3
9  ztag1
```

**I want the data output as:**

```
A
atag1
atag2

C
ctag1
ctag2

D
dtag1

E
etag1
etag2

Z
ztag1
```

**Started with this:**

```
select name from blog_tags order by name;
```

**what will be mysql query for this?**

Comment: SQL is the wrong language for that output.

Comment: Is this the real data, or just a dummy sample?

Comment: dummy sample given here

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application level code

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
select  name
from    (
    select  distinct upper(substring(name, 1, 1)) as name
    from    blog_tags
    union all
    select  name
    from    blog_tags
         ) 
order by name
```

**Edit**

If you want to get raw data for application level manipulation, I would suggest querying the db this way

```
select  upper(substring(name, 1, 1)) as key,
        name
from    blog_tags
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: can we make separate grouped arrays for every unique  characters?

Comment: You mean having a new line after each group?

Comment: key value pair array will be better like
`["A" => [
        [ "id" => "1", "name" => "atag1" ],
        [ "id" => "2", "name" => "atag2" ]
    ],
    "C" => [
        [ "id" => "3", "name" => "ctag1" ],
        [ "id" => "4", "name" => "ctag2" ]
    ]
]`

Comment: You could try to achieve that in a stored procedure, but I'd suggest to get the raw data in a simple query and manipulate it at application level, which will give you much more power and versatility. I edited my answer to provide a query for that.

Comment: Implemented this at application level. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bellow query to achieve this as given below

```
select substr(name,1,1),group_conact(name) from blog_tags group by substr(name,1,1);
```

This query will group the name's by first character and will group concat the name's as comma separated. You can convert the result from your programming language to array

The output will be like given below

```
substr(name,1,1)  group_conact(name)
    A             atag1,atag2

    C             ctag1,ctag2
```

Comment: I think you are confused about the requirement.